# MySQL select returns no rows while there are many

Tags: mysql, django

I'm using django to create a database and I manually created a test values in the database by creating objects and saving them to the database. 
Now when I run this query:

```
select TABLE_NAME, 
       TABLE_ROWS 
from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema = 'test_test_db';
```

It returns the tables with the correct number of rows. For example, a table 'accounts_users' has 4269 rows.

But when I try to select any values using `select username from accounts_users;`, I get 0 rows back or 'Empty Set' result.

And of course my django app cannot run because there is "no" data in the database.

What is wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you are connected to the right database?

Comment: yup I'm sure I selected the right one

Comment: Assuming this is not a production DB yet, I'd try inserting test values into `accounts_users`, and see if you can get values back out of it then. You could also confirm that, after inserting additional rows, the row count from `information_schema.tables` has updated. If the `INSERT` lets you `SELECT` a row back, and the row count from `tables` hasn't updated, maybe you are looking at different copies of your table after all.

Comment: Did you try dropping the django user and re granting django access?

Comment: I tried manually adding a test user and the TABLE_ROWS was updated "4270" but when I select I get only the test user I added.

Anyway, I learned that TABLE_ROWS is only a rough estimate and I guess it is not updated regularly enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried manually adding a test user and the TABLE_ROWS was updated "4270" but when I select I get only the test user I added. Anyway, I learned that TABLE_ROWS is only a rough estimate and I guess it is not updated regularly enough.

Comment: Rarely is `TABLE_ROWS` off by more than a factor of two.  I have never seen a non-zero value for an empty table.  So, I think there is still something wrong here, but I can't think what.